Possibly orphan taken in by two brothers (?) in a strange house
It seems the movie is from the 80's or 90's.
It's pretty sure it's an american movie.
My brother remembers a boy, possibly an orphan (about 8-12 yrs), who gets taken in by two men who might be brothers (possibly his uncles), maybe in their 50s, living in a rather strange apartment, somewhat dimly lit, but what stuck with him the most were stacks of old newspapers everywhere, reaching the ceiling.
The run-down look and the seclusion of the apartment didn't stand in the way of creating somewhat of a home and shelter for the boy, from the outside world, offering a certain protection the two men created for themselves.
There isn't much information on the plot, sadly.
It's a heartwarming feelgood-movie (not the corny kind, rather weird and with some depth to it), with a strange atmosphere and slow tempo.
Does anybody remember seeing a movie matching this description?
We'll try to answer any arising questions, but right now we can't think of more helpful details.

This sounds like Diane Keaton's film Unstrung Heroes from 1995 with Andie MacDowell, John Turturro and Michael Richards, but the kid's not exactly an orphan.

Steven Lidz, unhappy with his home life since his mother got sick, goes and lives with his two crazy uncles. There he changes and gets closer to his uncles, but his parents want him home even though he is finally happy and popular.

One of the crazy uncles is a hoarder and stacks huge piles of newspapers there. Here's the trailer:



